# Do any historical Jewish sources mention the translation and production of the Peshitta?

Tags: hebrew, translation, aramaic, targumin

There seems to be [much scholarly debate](https://www.jstor.org/stable/528619) surrounding when the Peshitta was translated from Hebrew to Aramaic, and whether it was the work of Jews or Christians.

In light of this, I am wondering if any Jewish sources from the time mention the Peshitta, and if so, is it in a positive or negative light?

I am also wondering if the text of the Peshitta, as currently received, is considered a valid Targum from a modern Jewish standpoint.

Comment: Do you have any examples of the 'scholarly debate' that you can source please?

Comment: It is unlikely to be much Jewish discussion about a translation of the Bible into Syrian Aramaic  intended for non-Jews. Being that the Peshitto includes the Christian bible that should preclude the possibility of it being of (rabbinic) Jewish origin

Comment: Bearing in mind @Schmerel 's comments, I wonder whether this question is on-topic for this site.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok The Peshitta is comprised of two different works of translation made by different people. One is a translation of the Tanach which may or may not have been made by Jews, and the other of the NT, made by Christians.

Comment: https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37701&st=&pgnum=5

Comment: Interestingly, some believe it was mentioned by Maimonides in Iggeret Teiman (Letter to Yemen).